# SOAPUI JUnit Reports not generated for individual test steps

Tags: junit, jenkins, reporting, soapui, functional-testing

My test will fetch test input data from a csv file and sticks them in my soapui's http request and fires them to target server. Since there are 1000s of inputs in my csv file, I cannot have individual test case for each individual input data. Therefore I just have one http test request (for numerous inputs.). A simple data driven approach.

I am using Jenkins to run my test, unfortunately in my junit report I just see 1 test case fail (or pass, if all the iteration passed) and nothing else

Instead I would like to have a junit report that will have each individual steps considered as individual test case. In general a report that will be based on test steps level.

Any help in this is really appreciated.

I allow SOAPUI to run and create junit reports uning the following command (as part of Jenkins)

```
sh /home/test/SmartBear/soapUI-Pro-4.5.2/bin/testrunner.sh -a -j -r -f/var/www/SOAPUI/Reports/ -ehttp://mytestserver.com/cgi-bin/test.fcgi -FDF -EDefault -I -S MySOAPUI_TestProjectFile.xml
```

Comment: This is a very good question and i'll really like to know how u solve it whenever you do. I also had a similar problem and i went with a work around by creating an HTML report. I would update the excel with pass fail status and capture all the details require for the report and generate the report.

Comment: I referred to a thread from SmartBear forum and followed the below steps:

Comment: what steps? Can you provide the link to the forum post?

Comment: I referred to a thread in a different forum and followed the below steps. a) Installed maven,created a test project using maven b) Modified the pom.xml file of the project to include <pluginRepositories>, soapui project xml file, output folder for junit report c) Now, I could run my soapui project using maven command. Referred to maven-soapui-plugin wiki and read that we can override the JunitReportCollector instance methods to customize default junit reporting. Now, I am stuck where to add this customized new JunitReportCollector (jar/class) file for SOAPUI to pick up when generating report.

Comment: Here's the maven-soapui-plugin wiki page that I referred: https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin/wiki/Tips#wiki-config-junit-reports

Comment: I'll try this out and you should really put this up as the answer as i am sure there are others who had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy.  In SoapUI, instead of putting multiple tests steps in one test case, just put each test step in its own test case.  Then, the report will show separation of each step on the report.